# Unable to add and render multiset data to the Remote API for PHPGraphLib

Tags: php, laravel, phpgraphlib

I am using the remote API for the library.

#### My Data Structure

```
$graph = new \stdclass;
$graph->width = 500;
$graph->height = 350;
$data1 = array('gross'=>23, 'taxed'=>45, 'discount'=>20, 'revenue'=>32, 'due'=>14);
$data2 = array('gross'=>15, 'taxed'=>23, 'discount'=>23,'revenue'=>12, 'due'=>17);
$data3 = array('gross'=>43, 'taxed'=>23, 'discount'=>34, 'revenue'=>16, 'due'=>20);
$graph->data = array($data1,$data2,$data3);
$graph->setBarColor = array('blue','green','yellow');
$graph->setLegend = 'true';
$graph->setLegendTitle = array('Today','MTD','YTD');
$graph->setTitle = 'Revenue Stats';
$graph->setTitleLocation = 'left';
//JSON encode graph object
$encoded = urlencode(json_encode($graph));
//retrieve XML
$target = 'http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/api/?g=' . $encoded . '&type=xml';`
```

#### ERROR

```
(2/2) Exception
String could not be parsed as XML
(1/2) ErrorException
SimpleXMLElement::__construct():
Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found
```

Works fine with a single dataset, but I am unable to load with multiple datasets.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: dump the content returned

Comment: @LawrenceCherone $xml_object =  new \SimpleXMLElement($target, NULL, TRUE); is after the $target line

Comment: Whats the value of `$target`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Are you sure it doesn't support multidimensional data?It says Syntax is different, but similar, to the regular PHPGraphLib library. And the original library does support multi dimensional data.

Comment: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/api/?g=%7B%22width%22%3A500%2C%22height%22%3A350%2C%22data%22%3A%5B%7B%22gross%22%3A23%2C%22taxed%22%3A45%2C%22discount%22%3A20%2C%22revenue%22%3A32%2C%22due%22%3A14%7D%2C%7B%22gross%22%3A15%2C%22taxed%22%3A23%2C%22discount%22%3A23%2C%22revenue%22%3A12%2C%22due%22%3A17%7D%2C%7B%22gross%22%3A43%2C%22taxed%22%3A23%2C%22discount%22%3A34%2C%22revenue%22%3A16%2C%22due%22%3A20%7D%5D%2C%22setBarColor%22%3A%5B%22blue%22%2C%22green%22%2C%22yellow%22%5D%2C%22setLegend%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22setLegendTitle%22%3A%5B%22Today%22%2C%22MTD%22%2C%22YTD%22%5D%2C%22setTitle

Comment: %22%3A%22Revenue+Stats%22%2C%22setTitleLocation%22%3A%22left%22%7D&type=xml

Comment: Sorry the link was too lengthy to add in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API does not support it, its broken.. a simple check of the [URL](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/api/?g=%7B%22width%22%3A500%2C%22height%22%3A350%2C%22data%22%3A%5B%7B%22gross%22%3A23%2C%22taxed%22%3A45%2C%22discount%22%3A20%2C%22revenue%22%3A32%2C%22due%22%3A14%7D%2C%7B%22gross%22%3A15%2C%22taxed%22%3A23%2C%22discount%22%3A23%2C%22revenue%22%3A12%2C%22due%22%3A17%7D%2C%7B%22gross%22%3A43%2C%22taxed%22%3A23%2C%22discount%22%3A34%2C%22revenue%22%3A16%2C%22due%22%3A20%7D%5D%2C%22setBarColor%22%3A%5B%22blue%22%2C%22green%22%2C%22yellow%22%5D%2C%22setLegend%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22setLegendTitle%22%3A%5B%22Today%22%2C%22MTD%22%2C%22YTD%22%5D%2C%22setTitle%22%3A%22Revenue%20Stats%22%2C%22setTitleLocation%22%3A%22left%22%7D&type=xml) produces some invalid XML.

```
$this->data[0],$this->data[1],$this->data[2]<br><br>$graph->addData($this->data[0],$this->data[1],$this->data[2]);<br><?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpgrahphlib>
    <imageName>230_0046831d980a56de52331b09b7eb7efc.png</imageName>
    <imageLocation>http://www.ebrueggeman.com/sites/www.ebrueggeman.com/files/phpgraphlib_api/230_0046831d980a56de52331b09b7eb7efc.png</imageLocation>
    <imageTag><![CDATA[<img width="500" height="350" src="http://www.ebrueggeman.com/sites/www.ebrueggeman.com/files/phpgraphlib_api/230_0046831d980a56de52331b09b7eb7efc.png" />]]></imageTag>
    <error></error>
    <version>2.30</version>
</phpgrahphlib>
```

But does generate the graph:

[image]

So you could attempt to remove everything before `<?` then just use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php). Might want to report a bug so it's fixed.

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents($target);

$target = strstr($xml, '<?');

$xml_object =  simplexml_load_string($target);

echo 'Image Tag: '. $xml_object->imageTag.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Errors: '. $xml_object->error.PHP_EOL;
```

https://3v4l.org/abHqm

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help, i will try with the library itself,instead of the API.

Comment: That's a quite unusual thing. Well thanks a lot, I will post a bug on their Github page.